# R - Matching Data Frames

Tags: r, search, match

I have the following issue related with matching different data frames.

In the first place, I have the next table:

```
table<-data.frame(brand=c('duna','cars','cars','sea','sea','sea','mega','moon','moon'),model=c('mm','mm','mm','ll','ll','ll','tr','tr','tr'),version=c("2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi","2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p","2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p","2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p","1.8 sx  5-p","1.0 mpfi joy 8v","hatch ls 1.0 8v","2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p","1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p"))

  brand model                            version
1  duna    mm          2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi
2  cars    mm      2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p
3  cars    mm   2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p
4   sea    ll       2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p
5   sea    ll                        1.8 sx  5-p
6   sea    ll                    1.0 mpfi joy 8v
7  mega    tr                    hatch ls 1.0 8v
8  moon    tr 2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p
9  moon    tr           1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p
```

And I have to match it with the next one:

```
table_match<-data.frame(brand=c('duna','cars','sea','mega','moon'),model=c('mm','mm','ll','tr','tr'),version=c('tdi','ls','xl','ls','xlt'))

table_match$id<-paste0(table_match$brand,table_match$model,table_match$version)

  brand model version        id
1  duna    mm     tdi dunammtdi
2  cars    mm      ls  carsmmls
3   sea    ll      xl   seallxl
4  mega    tr      ls  megatrls
5  moon    tr     xlt moontrxlt
```

So, the issue here is to match `brand`, `model` and `version` from `table_match` into `table`.

For example, in `table` if `brand=duna`, `model=mm` and `version` contains the exact word `"tdi"`, then it is a matching! so the `id`(in `table_match`), with that matching, will be located next to `version`.

```
  brand model                            version    match
1  duna    mm          2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi     dunammtdi
2  cars    mm      2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p   
3  cars    mm   2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p     carsmmls
4   sea    ll       2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p     seallxl
5   sea    ll                        1.8 sx  5-p
6   sea    ll                    1.0 mpfi joy 8v
7  mega    tr                    hatch ls 1.0 8v     megatrls
8  moon    tr 2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p     moontrxlt
9  moon    tr           1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p     moontrxlt
```

Comment: Suggest look at package `fuzzyjoin` which uses a provided function to do the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fuzzy_join on two equal conditions `==` and the third `str_detect` from `stringr`. I don't know why the fuzzy join makes three duplicates of each, so added `unique()`
NOTE: added `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` to test data

```
table<-data.frame(brand=c('duna','cars','cars','sea','sea','sea','mega','moon','moon'),
                  model=c('mm','mm','mm','ll','ll','ll','tr','tr','tr'),
                  version=c("2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi","2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p","2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p","2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p","1.8 sx  5-p","1.0 mpfi joy 8v","hatch ls 1.0 8v","2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p","1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p")
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
table_match<-data.frame(brand=c('duna','cars','sea','mega','moon'),
                        model=c('mm','mm','ll','tr','tr'),
                        version=c('tdi','ls','xl','ls','xlt'),
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)

fuzzy_join(table, table_match, 
  by = c("brand", "model", "version"), 
  match_fun = c(`==`, `==`, function(x,y) { str_detect(x, paste0("\\b", y, "\\b" ))})) %>%
  unique()

#    brand.x model.x                          version.x brand.y model.y version.y
# 1     duna      mm          2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi    duna      mm       tdi
# 4     cars      mm   2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p    cars      mm        ls
# 7      sea      ll       2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p     sea      ll        xl
# 10    mega      tr                    hatch ls 1.0 8v    mega      tr        ls
# 13    moon      tr 2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p    moon      tr       xlt
# 16    moon      tr           1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p    moon      tr       xlt
```

Comment: Your code matches the string `lsdakar` which is not what the original poster wanted, if you look at his example output.

Comment: Corrected with regex from @Kristoferson and adding unique()

Comment: Excellent contribution!. Besides, with the paste0 including boundary words it matches exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 3):

I think we can just do a merge and then filter it down using regex. Give this a shot

```
dat = merge(table, table_match, by = c("brand", "model"))


dat$match = mapply(function(x, y) grepl(paste("\\b", x, "\\b", sep = ""), y), dat$version.y, dat$version.x)

dat$match = ifelse(dat$match, dat$id, "")
dat = dat[ , !colnames(dat) %in% c("version.y", "id")]
colnames(dat)[3] = "version"

dat = dat[with(dat, order(brand)), ]

brand model                            version     match
1  cars    mm    2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p          
2  cars    mm   2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p  carsmmls
3  duna    mm          2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi dunammtdi
4  mega    tr                    hatch ls 1.0 8v  megatrls
5  moon    tr 2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p moontrxlt
6  moon    tr           1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p moontrxlt
7   sea    ll       2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p   seallxl
8   sea    ll                        1.8 sx  5-p          
9   sea    ll                    1.0 mpfi joy 8v
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `regex_join()` from the `fuzzyjoin` package. N.B. I have added space around the string 'ls' in `table_match` so that the regular expression does not match the string 'lsdakar' in `table`, since this is not what the original poster wanted.

```
library(fuzzyjoin)

# Use data_frame() to get rid of stringsAsFactors problem
table <-
data_frame(
    brand = c('duna', 'cars', 'cars', 'sea', 'sea', 'sea', 'mega', 'moon', 'moon'),
    model = c('mm', 'mm', 'mm', 'll', 'll', 'll', 'tr', 'tr', 'tr'),
    version = c(
      "2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi",
      "2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p",
      "2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p",
      "2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p",
      "1.8 sx  5-p",
      "1.0 mpfi joy 8v",
      "hatch ls 1.0 8v",
      "2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p",
      "1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p"
    )
  )

# Use data_frame() here too
table_match <-
  data_frame(
    brand = c('duna', 'cars', 'sea', 'mega', 'moon'),
    model = c('mm', 'mm', 'll', 'tr', 'tr'),
    version = c('tdi', ' ls ', 'xl', ' ls ', 'xlt')
  )

# Use regex_semi_join to find the matches
regex_semi_join(table, table_match, by = c(brand = "brand", 
  model = "model", version = "version"))

# A tibble: 6 × 3
  brand model                            version
  <chr> <chr>                              <chr>
1  duna    mm          2.8 sr cab. dupla 4x4 tdi
2  cars    mm   2.4 ls cab. simples 4x2 flex 2-p
3   sea    ll       2.3 xl cab. simples 4x2  2-p
4  mega    tr                    hatch ls 1.0 8v
5  moon    tr 2.3 xlt cab. dupla 4x2 limited 4-p
6  moon    tr           1.4 fire ce xlt flex 2-p
> 

# Use regex_anti_join to find the non-matches
regex_anti_join(table, table_match, by = c(brand = "brand", 
  model = "model", version = "version"))

# A tibble: 3 × 3
  brand model                         version
  <chr> <chr>                           <chr>
1  cars    mm 2.0 lsdakar 16v 4x4 hi-flex 5-p
2   sea    ll                     1.8 sx  5-p
3   sea    ll                 1.0 mpfi joy 8v
>
```